# Inserting Java Object to MongoDB with date value inserted as String

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the below mongoDB code with Java, I am trying to insert the TechnologyDetails to mongoDB,
and in the mapper method I am setting all the values and persisting to DB. The problem is as the collection.insertOne() takes only document as an argument, after I convert the TechnologyDetails pojo to Document, during insertion to MongoDB the "createdAt" Date datatype field is being inserted as String to DB. Could anyone help on this, how to maintain the same dataType even after converting the pojo to Document. So that I insert Date as Date to mongoDb. Thanks.

```
final FindIterable<Document> iterable = technologiesCollection
                    .find(and(eq(APPLICATION, techKey.getApplication()), eq(VERSION, techKey.getVersion()),
                            eq(TECHNOLOGY, techKey.getTechnology())));
            final Document document = iterable.first();

            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final TechnologyDetails technology = mapper.convertValue(document, TechnologyDetails.class);        

            if (technology == null) {
               //mapper method to set the technology fields
                Document tech = mapper(techKey, hosts);         
                try {
                    technologiesCollection.insertOne(tech);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("error", e);
                }

            }

    private Document mapper(final TechnologyKey techKey, final Set<ApplicationHost> hosts) {
            final TechnologyDetails technology = new TechnologyDetails();
            final TransactionDetail txnDetail = new TransactionDetail();
            final UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
            technology.setApplication(techKey.getApplication());
            technology.setVersion(techKey.getVersion());
            technology.setTechnology(techKey.getTechnology());
            if (hosts != null) {
                technology.setApplicationHosts(hosts);
            }
            userDetail.setDsid("123");
            userDetail.setName("APP");
            txnDetail.setCreatedBy(userDetail);
            final Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            txnDetail.setCreatedAt(date);
            technology.setTxnDetails(txnDetail);
            Document document = Document.parse(new JSONObject(technology).toString());
            return document;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an ODM

https://www.baeldung.com/mongodb-morphia